# Highslide JS : problems autoload

Tags: javascript, highslide

I just suscribe in this forum because of some problems caused by the use of HighslideJS. First I really have to thank you because it works perfectly. It is a great big job !
Then I have to you inform I speak not really good english so be indulgent please, I will to try to do the max to be understood.

Let's go.
So I tried to use Highslide with an autoloading and without any thumbnail (they are hidden because of the  css rule : visibility:hidden on the block div). 
I would like **use it like a div block in a relative position** : like that I maybe could place it in my web page where I want. But I can't. that doesn't work. I think it's because it still works like a popup. But I don't know how change it.

And I would like too that **nobody can't close it**. I tried to understand the function close but I can't. I write in my javascript file : hs.close = false; but it doesn't work.
I don't know how can I do. When I do "Enter" on my computer keyboard It closes itself... Is it possible to prevent it ?

I have got an other problem with the **white big button** (actually my button uses the following functions : Prev/Play/Next) : It appears twice. Once at the location where I want, and another at the top on the left of my web page. I don't know why but I note when I comment this part of my javascript file :

```
hs.addSlideshow({
        //slideshowGroup: 'group1',
        interval: 2000
        //...
)}
```

Like that the second button disappears (this one which is not on the good place... cool). it seems to work but I don't know if it's the good way to do.

Thanks for your help.
Claire

---

ANSWERS :

***Thanks EarlyOut for your help*** : It's possible to solve the automatic closing using this code in the js file :

```
hs.onKeyDown = function(sender, e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 27 || e.keyCode == 33 || e.keyCode == 34 || e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 70) return false;
        if(e.keyCode == 32) return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to provide any help without being able to see your page. But this example might be useful:

http://jgromit.com/matrixslide/standardMS/

Look at the HTML, and also at the res/hsconfig.js file. In the config file, you'll see some extra coding to ignore certain keyboard inputs and to disable closing of the popup when the visitor clicks outside the image area.